# How to find usage (memory) of databases inside a Google CloudSQL instance?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, gcp

I run multiple databases inside a single CloudSQL instance. My problem is that I cannot get monitoring insights at the individual database level. For example, if I want to know how much memory a particular database is causing, I cannot find that. Google's monitoring for CloudSQL shows the total instance level resource utilisation. Does anyone have any helpful ideas on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the database as mysql: Just write a script to calculate the memory (like the innodb_buffer_pool_size/sort_buffer_size and other buffer parameters) and then calculate the memory with max connections utilization and the number of connections happening at the moment.

In that way we can check the database memory.